# Codeigniter session class not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I loaded the session class in autoload.php, but when I use the CodeIgniter session nothing happens.

Example: I set flash data:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'HELP!');
```

When I print this information nothing happens!

Example:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('message');
```

What is the problem with my code?

NOTE: I'm having problems with CodeIgniter Session in general, problem with set_flashdata and set_userdata.

UPDATE:

It was a server problem, now it's solved.
Thanks for all!

Comment: Flash data is only available for the NEXT http request. Are you making another request? If so, are you making only one?

Comment: Yes, I'm making another request and only one.

Comment: Are you certain its just one request being made?

Comment: Yes, I'm having problems with CodeIgniter Session in general.
Problem with set_flashdata and set_userdata.

Comment: Please edit you question with your session config.php stuff

Answer (score 2):

flash data is only available to you for the next server request within that specific session . means if you made another request or put a redirect after loading a view then the flash message will not appear . and other then this dont forget to add a encryption_key key in config file auto loading session library and not try to redirect to another page after loading a view . hope this will answer your question

Comment: Yes, I'm making another request and only one.
I'm having problems with CodeIgniter Session in general. Problem with set_flashdata and set_userdata, I didn't forget the encryption_key.

Comment: can you share the code so i have a better understanding how you are making requests

Comment: See this example:

if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                redirect('/', 'refresh');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
                redirect('auth/login', 'refresh'); 
            }

Comment: this should be available i did not understand y this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happen because this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'HELP!');
```

Is just setting 'HELP' in the  session 'message';

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'WOOPS!');
```

You need to set also some conditions in your view in order to read the session and see the result:

```
<?php
    if($this->session->flashdata('message'))
    {
        ?>
          <div class="container" style="padding-top:80px;">
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
    }elseif($this->session->flashdata('error')){
      ?>
          <div class="container" style="padding-top:80px;">
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error');?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

As you can see there are here two examples one for the message (success) and one for the error (fail)

**EDIT:**

As a reaction of your comment I post this here because in the comment wont be readable:

As you say you have already done this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```

Do you also have set this in the config?

```
 $config['encryption_key'] = 'DCF564RT9JN761AZX56FR76Rd8hg6s12';

$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: This is not my problem.
I know how to print flashdata and check if is set.
I'm having problem with codeigniter session in general, problem with set_flashdata and set_userdata.

Comment: I have an edit in the answer. I posted there because will be not readable in here. This is a strange issue.

Comment: Yes, I already had done this configuration and it didn't work

Comment: Ok, great. Do you have in your database a table named `ci_session`?

Comment: I have, but this is not the problem, the codeigniter session works with no database

Comment: As you can see in the configuration the session needs a driver which can be  files, database, redis, memcached. Also your browser has to accept cookies. I am just trying to help you close out all the possibilities. This is very very strange the Codeigniter session works just fine by default. Is this the first time you are using the session?

Comment: I really would like to see the method in your controller where you are setting the session and how you are loading the view and if the view is the one where you check if the session exist.

Comment: Now I'm not in my work xD. But thanks for all! Tomorow I will see what is going on with it

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version Codeigniter (Version 3.1.6)  from [Codeigniter official website](https://codeigniter.com) and replace the system folder to your Codeigniter project and it will works.